# Can I set an instance's custom property with an attribute node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've successfully created a little "pointed cube" object with geometry nodes - a cube with a pointed "roof", where the roof height is controlled by the node setup:
[image: pointed cube nodes]

so there is an input field "tipheight" that I can use to change the shape of the pointed cube.

Now I'd like to use this object as an instance, scattered across a a plane, and with the roof height randomized from instance to instance.

So in my plane I have a simple node setup where I do a point distribute and then use the point instance node to instantiate pointed cubes.  But I don't see how to randomize "tipheight" for the instances.

- I tried simply using the attribute randomize to set an attribute "tipheight" but it didn't work.
- I've tried various other geometry nodes to find one that could affect the instance's input property (custom object property?  I'm not sure about the terminology, sorry)

Is this kind of manipulation of sub-instance properties possible?

---

Blend file
[image]

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide your blend file so we don't have to reproduce ourselves everything....

Comment: I don't know if it's possible since it's a custom property on the object, and geometry nodes modify geometry data blocks. Have you considered using a shape key and vertex groups for that ?

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I've added my .blend file.  I am looking for how to set an object's custom property.  The goal is to build objects with many custom properties that can then be reused in many places, and their users (the point-distribute of some other .blend file) can manipulate them with attributes.  I hope.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with this setup (i have two objects, roof + house):

[image]

result:

[image]

and i would really appreciate if you post your blend file to make the life for us who want to help easier and less time consuming. You want help, right? so please make our life easier because we solve your problems. Thank you.

and if you improve this a bit you will get this:

[image]

video tutorial:
https://youtu.be/N0dNAtggfDU